# In JSON how to display all the datas in an table in JS

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm Trying to display all the data in an table but i'm facing some issues. can any one please help me to solve this. Thanks in Advance..

```
var obj=[
            {
                id : "01",
                name : "Bob",
                prof : "Soft Engg"
            },
            {
                id : "02",
                name : "George",
                prof : "Admin"
            },
            {
                id : "03",
                name : "Paul",
                prof : "Front End"
            }
        ];
    var x = document.createElement("table");
    x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
    document.body.appendChild(x);

    var y = document.createElement("tr");
    y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");

    for(i=0; i<obj.length;i++) {
      document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);  
      var z = document.createElement("td");
      var t = document.createTextNode(obj[i]["id"]);
      z.appendChild(t);
      document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(z); 
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/biveqifomo/edit?js,output)

Comment: What do you **exactly** want to display?

Comment: need new row every iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want all the data in your list of objects, then you need to add a row for each object and a cell for each attribute for that object (id, name, prof).  Right now you only add one row, and then only

Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/n3va9cme/

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
document.body.appendChild(table);

for(i=0; i<obj.length;i++) {
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  table.appendChild(row);

  for (key in obj[i]) {
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(cell);
    cell.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
  } 
}
```

Comment: Works Fine Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 1):

try that

```
var obj=[
    {
        id : "001",
        name : "apple",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "red"
    },
    {
        id : "002",
        name : "melon",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "green"
    },
    {
        id : "003",
        name : "banana",
        category : "fruit",
        color : "yellow"
    }
];
var x = document.createElement("table");
x.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
document.body.appendChild(x);

var y = document.createElement("tr");
y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");

for(i=0; i<obj.length;i++) {

  document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(y);  

  var y = document.createElement("tr");
  y.setAttribute("id", "myTr");
  var z = document.createElement("td");
  var t = document.createTextNode(obj[i]["id"]);
  var u = document.createTextNode(obj[i]["name"]);
  var n = document.createTextNode(obj[i]["category"]);
  var m = document.createTextNode(obj[i]["color"]);

  z.appendChild(t);
  z.appendChild(u);
  z.appendChild(n);
  z.appendChild(m);
  y.appendChild(z); 

  document.getElementById("myTr").appendChild(y);
}
```

Comment: Thank's Let Me try :)